# 14.04.1: USB 1-1.6 device descriptor read/64, error -32 Spam

Tags: 14.04, usb, tty

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro S500. All my USB ports are in use (including the eSATA/USB combo port), with a keyboard, mouse, Logitech G430 Headset, and Lexar USB

When in tty#/Ctrl+Alt+F# terminal, I get occasional (every 10 seconds) annoying messages with the line `USB 1-1.6 device descriptor read/64, error -32`.

And I don't understand why. It only happens in TTYs, and I tried unplugging all my USB devices, yet the message continued, which makes me think it's a hub in my laptop causing the message.

I don't experience any USB problems, and how can I prevent the message from coming up in the future  when in TTYs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Among the USB devices you have listed, I don't see a USB powered cooling fan.  I suspect your laptop is overheating.  If your laptop has been used long enough, which is some cases is as little as 6 months, it's heatsink might be so clogged with dust that a cooling pad might not make enough difference.

When you get a chance please turn off and unplug your laptop.  Close it.  Turn it upside down and blow as hard as you can into the port where the hot are normally exits.  If you keep your eyes open you may be amazed by what you see.  This is typically one of the first things I do when examining a malfunctioning laptop.  I teach this "trick" to everyone I know.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however it wasn't overheating. Instead, it was Bluetooth when I turned it off in indicator-bluetooth-service. Something was re-enabling it, which caused the USB 1-1.6 spam. Link to tail of /var/log/kern.log: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0AaKk1N-0kXekJXSm1SUWhKODA/view?usp=sharing) I turned Bluetooth on at 1098